# Need to know settings to download full mail items for IMAP account in Outlook 2013

Tags: imap, microsoft-outlook-2013, cached-exchange-mode

I'm using IMAP account in Outlook 2013 and I need to set my settings as default that whenever a mail arrives it is downloaded fully.
Currently when I click to read a mail it takes time to download items in that mail.
I want such settings that whenever (even in offline mode also) I open that mail it shows full mail.
After searching on net, I found that there should be an option "Cached Exchange mode" in File--Account Settings-Account settings-Double click Exchange account--More settings--Advance Tab--Cached exchange mode settings.
But in my Outlook there is no such option under Advance tab.
Can anyone help on this please.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, cached exchange mode should only be present when using an email account set up with an Exchange ActiveSync server.

There is an option to keep all mail offline by going to:

File -> Account Settings -> Account Settings -> Click on the address setup with IMAP -> Click "Change" -> Move slider for "Mail to keep offline:" to the right.